# Partial join of two rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following dataset

```
id | date       | metadata | details
------------------------------------------
1  | 2020-01-01 | fruit    | null
1  | null       | null     | banana, apple
2  | 2020-02-02 | dairy    | null     
2  | null       | null     | milk, yogurt
```

I want to "merge" these two rows so that it looks like this

```
id | date       | metadata | details
------------------------------------------
1  | 2020-01-01 | fruit    | banana, apple
2  | 2020-02-02 | dairy    | milk, yogurt
```

I would like to move the row with a non null `details` column into the null one. Could I get some guidance on how I could get to this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate using max(). As aggregate functions ignore NULL values, it will get you the result you want.

```
select id, 
       max(date) as date, 
       max(metadata) as metadata, 
       max(details) as details
from the_table
group by id;
```